# How to increase the idle timeout settings in Azure SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-server

As per the Microsoft documentation

```
In these circumstances, SQL Azure will close an already established connection:

An idle connection was held by an application for more than 30 minutes.
You went to lunch and left your SQL Server Management Studio connection for longer than 30 minutes
```

Is there any way to increase the above mentioned duration to 2 hours?

Comment: That's not documentation.  That quote is from a blog published in 2010.  12 years ago.  The documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/  A lot has changed in Azure SQL Database Connectivity and the client libraries to mitigate transient connection failures.  Do you have an actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am using Azure SQL Server Hypescale database. I have an application that needs to keep the connections opened for 2 hours but I see that Idle connections are getting closed in 30 minutes.

Comment: What client library are you using?  Are you using connection pooling?

Comment: I am using - "DBCP 1.4"  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html

Comment: Are you using the Microsoft JDBC driver? See [Connection resiliency (JDBC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connection-resiliency?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Yes, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/7.4.1.jre8

Comment: I am migrating the database from Oracle to Azure SQL Server. I have a spring batch application that would run for 2 hours continuously. I am using - "DBCP 1.4" https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html and SQL JDBC 7.4.1, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/7.4.1.jre8.  This application is running for 30mins without any issues and started failing with the error message "Connection is closed"

Comment: Can you use the Redirect connection policy with a TCP Keepalive? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-to-an-azure-sql-database?view=sql-server-ver15#connections-dropped

Comment: My target environment is Azure Kubernetes and I would be using Ubuntu as my base image. I am not sure how to implement Redirect connection policy with a TCP Keepalive in Ubuntu. any suggestions?

Comment: The connection policy is set on the database, and the default should use "Redirect" from inside Azure.  How to configure TCP Keepalive in in AKS, I don't know.  But I think it's a kernel setting, so would be an AKS Node config, not a container config. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/custom-node-configuration